# File Exists always return false

Tags: c#, .net, image, url

```
ImageURL = String.Format(@"../Uploads/docs/{0}/Logo.jpg", SellerID);
if (!File.Exists(ImageURL))
{
    ImageURL = String.Format(@"../Uploads/docs/defaultLogo.jpg", SellerID);
}
```

Everytime I check if there is file, I get the default logo in image, is there something beyond permission to check.

> Note: this is class library referenced on website

Comment: Is this code being run remotely or locally from within a website/service?

Comment: its on local, however i get the defaultLogo but file exists does seem to work for only complete url, any indepth about how file exists works, any link??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give physical path instead of virtual path (url) you can use webRequest to find if file exists on given `url`. You can read this [article](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-check-remote-file-exists-using-c/) to see different methods for check if resource at given url exists.

```
private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
    try
    {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //Getting the Web Response.
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Any exception will returns false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit** based on comments, *running the code on server hosting the files accessed by url*. I assume your upload folder is on root of web site directory.

```
ImageURL = String.Format(@"/Uploads/docs/{0}/Logo.jpg", SellerID);
if(!File.Exists(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ImageURL))
{

}
```

Comment: sorry to inform you late but its on class library referenced on web application

Comment: I am on local so normal File.Exists would have done I guess but its not working

Comment: If you are on same machine where files  are located then, use it like if(!File.Exists(@"c:\temp\test.txt")){}

Answer (score 2):

If this is within a web application, the current directory is usually not what you think it is. For example if IIS is serving the web pages, the current directory may be where inetsrv.exe is or a temp directory. To get the path to your web application you can use

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"../Uploads/docs/defaultLogo.jpg");
bool fileExists = File.Exists(path);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx

MapPath will convert the path you give it into something relative to your web application. To make sure path is being set correctly you can use trace debugging with `Trace.Write` or write the path to a debug file (using an absolute path for the debug file).